# Numerical Integration and Fractional Decomposition (Apart)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerical-value

Suppose we want to perform the following integral:

$$I=2\int_{-1}^{1}f(e_0,s)g(e_0,s) \mathrm{d}s$$ with:

$$f(e_0,s)=\frac{16 s^2 \left(2 s^2-1\right) \left(8 s^4-8 s^2+1\right) \left(8 s^2 \left(8 s^4-14
   s^2+7\right)-7\right)-1}{\left(e_0 s+1\right){}^3}$$

and:

$$g(e_0,s)=\frac{\sqrt{1-s^2}}{\sqrt{2 e_0 s+e_0^2+1}}$$

If we suppose $e_0=0.3$ and using `NIntegrate` we get the correct result: $I=2.65521\times 10^{-7}$.

If instead before integrating we use the command `Apart` on $f(e_0,s)$ which gives the correct fractional decomposition:

```
(32 (-39936 + 91520 e0^2 - 76032 e0^4 + 27720 e0^6 - 4200 e0^8 + 
    189 e0^10))/e0^14 - (
 96 (-11264 + 24960 e0^2 - 19712 e0^4 + 6600 e0^6 - 840 e0^8 + 
    21 e0^10) s)/e0^13 - (
 128 (7040 - 14976 e0^2 + 11088 e0^4 - 3300 e0^6 + 
    315 e0^8) s^2)/e0^12 + (
 128 (5760 - 11648 e0^2 + 7920 e0^4 - 1980 e0^6 + 
    105 e0^8) s^3)/e0^11 + (
 768 (-768 + 1456 e0^2 - 880 e0^4 + 165 e0^6) s^4)/e0^10 - (
 256 (-1792 + 3120 e0^2 - 1584 e0^4 + 165 e0^6) s^5)/e0^9 - (
 2048 (168 - 260 e0^2 + 99 e0^4) s^6)/e0^8 + (
 6144 (40 - 52 e0^2 + 11 e0^4) s^7)/e0^7 + (
 4096 (-40 + 39 e0^2) s^8)/e0^6 - (4096 (-24 + 13 e0^2) s^9)/e0^5 - (
 49152 s^10)/e0^4 + (16384 s^11)/e0^3 + (
 16384 - 53248 e0^2 + 67584 e0^4 - 42240 e0^6 + 13440 e0^8 - 
  2016 e0^10 + 112 e0^12 - e0^14)/(e0^14 (1 + e0 s)^3) - (
 32 (7168 - 19968 e0^2 + 21120 e0^4 - 10560 e0^6 + 2520 e0^8 - 
    252 e0^10 + 7 e0^12))/(e0^14 (1 + e0 s)^2) + (
 16 (93184 - 219648 e0^2 + 190080 e0^4 - 73920 e0^6 + 12600 e0^8 - 
    756 e0^10 + 7 e0^12))/(e0^14 (1 + e0 s))
```

and then we integrate with `NIntegrate` the result is wrong: $I=-0.00630815$. Moreover after the decomposition of $f(e_0,s)$ is done it is possible to integrate term by term exactly, but still the result is wrong.

Why does this happens? and how to fix this problem?

Thank you so much in advance

The entire code is the following:

```
 
f[e0_, s_] := (-1 + 
  16 s^2 (-1 + 2 s^2) (1 - 8 s^2 + 8 s^4) (-7 + 
     8 s^2 (7 - 14 s^2 + 8 s^4)))/(1 + e0 s)^3

g[e0_, s_] := (Sqrt[1 - s^2]/ Sqrt[1 + e0^2 + 2 e0 s]) 

NIntegrate[2*f[0.3, s]*g[0.3, s], {s, -1, 1}]

Out[1248]= 2.65521*10^-7

Apart[f[e0, s], s]

Out[1249]= (
 32 (-39936 + 91520 e0^2 - 76032 e0^4 + 27720 e0^6 - 4200 e0^8 + 
    189 e0^10))/e0^14 - (
 96 (-11264 + 24960 e0^2 - 19712 e0^4 + 6600 e0^6 - 840 e0^8 + 
    21 e0^10) s)/e0^13 - (
 128 (7040 - 14976 e0^2 + 11088 e0^4 - 3300 e0^6 + 
    315 e0^8) s^2)/e0^12 + (
 128 (5760 - 11648 e0^2 + 7920 e0^4 - 1980 e0^6 + 
    105 e0^8) s^3)/e0^11 + (
 768 (-768 + 1456 e0^2 - 880 e0^4 + 165 e0^6) s^4)/e0^10 - (
 256 (-1792 + 3120 e0^2 - 1584 e0^4 + 165 e0^6) s^5)/e0^9 - (
 2048 (168 - 260 e0^2 + 99 e0^4) s^6)/e0^8 + (
 6144 (40 - 52 e0^2 + 11 e0^4) s^7)/e0^7 + (
 4096 (-40 + 39 e0^2) s^8)/e0^6 - (4096 (-24 + 13 e0^2) s^9)/e0^5 - (
 49152 s^10)/e0^4 + (16384 s^11)/e0^3 + (
 16384 - 53248 e0^2 + 67584 e0^4 - 42240 e0^6 + 13440 e0^8 - 
  2016 e0^10 + 112 e0^12 - e0^14)/(e0^14 (1 + e0 s)^3) - (
 32 (7168 - 19968 e0^2 + 21120 e0^4 - 10560 e0^6 + 2520 e0^8 - 
    252 e0^10 + 7 e0^12))/(e0^14 (1 + e0 s)^2) + (
 16 (93184 - 219648 e0^2 + 190080 e0^4 - 73920 e0^6 + 12600 e0^8 - 
    756 e0^10 + 7 e0^12))/(e0^14 (1 + e0 s))

 
q[e0_, s_] := (
  32 (-39936 + 91520 e0^2 - 76032 e0^4 + 27720 e0^6 - 4200 e0^8 + 
     189 e0^10))/e0^14 - (
  96 (-11264 + 24960 e0^2 - 19712 e0^4 + 6600 e0^6 - 840 e0^8 + 
     21 e0^10) s)/e0^13 - (
  128 (7040 - 14976 e0^2 + 11088 e0^4 - 3300 e0^6 + 315 e0^8) s^2)/
  e0^12 + (128 (5760 - 11648 e0^2 + 7920 e0^4 - 1980 e0^6 + 
     105 e0^8) s^3)/e0^11 + (
  768 (-768 + 1456 e0^2 - 880 e0^4 + 165 e0^6) s^4)/e0^10 - (
  256 (-1792 + 3120 e0^2 - 1584 e0^4 + 165 e0^6) s^5)/e0^9 - (
  2048 (168 - 260 e0^2 + 99 e0^4) s^6)/e0^8 + (
  6144 (40 - 52 e0^2 + 11 e0^4) s^7)/e0^7 + (
  4096 (-40 + 39 e0^2) s^8)/e0^6 - (4096 (-24 + 13 e0^2) s^9)/e0^5 - (
  49152 s^10)/e0^4 + (16384 s^11)/e0^3 + (
  16384 - 53248 e0^2 + 67584 e0^4 - 42240 e0^6 + 13440 e0^8 - 
   2016 e0^10 + 112 e0^12 - e0^14)/(e0^14 (1 + e0 s)^3) - (
  32 (7168 - 19968 e0^2 + 21120 e0^4 - 10560 e0^6 + 2520 e0^8 - 
     252 e0^10 + 7 e0^12))/(e0^14 (1 + e0 s)^2) + (
  16 (93184 - 219648 e0^2 + 190080 e0^4 - 73920 e0^6 + 12600 e0^8 - 
     756 e0^10 + 7 e0^12))/(e0^14 (1 + e0 s))

FullSimplify[q[e0, s] - f[e0, s]]

Out[1253]= 0

NIntegrate[2*q[0.3, s]*g[0.3, s], {s, -1, 1}]

Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in s near {s} = {-0.671906}. NIntegrate obtained -0.00630815 and 0.0006896853637019303` for the integral and error estimates.

Out[1251]= -0.00630815
```

Comment: Please post your Mathematica code. Chances are that there's a typo somewhere in your code.

Comment: I added the full code to the question. @Roman

Comment: Simply a problem of WorkingPrecision  `NIntegrate[2*q[3/10, s]*g[3/10, s], {s, -1, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 14] ` yields right result.

Comment: The warning offers a possible reason for the problem as "WorkingPrecision too small". You should pay closer attention to the warnings.

Comment: You claim that integrating term-by-term exactly gives a wrong result. Could you elaborate, that is, indicate how you tested this? (If it indicates a bug in `Integrate` I'll take a look, but I've spent more time there of late than I'd like so I'd rather avoid that if I can.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is massive cancellation in integrating that sum at machine precision.